# Redirect DispForm to EditForm using link from email link causes endless refresh of DispForm?

Tags: refresh

I am using the following CEWP at the end of my DispForm. This works if I simply navigate to DispForm from the list. If I use the link from the system generated email, the DispForm continues refreshes rather than redirecting to the EditForm. Any suggestions? The email is Sharepoint generated and the path is simple and direct.

window.onload=function(){
    var ActualURL = window.location.href;
    var SecondURL = ActualURL.replace("DispForm.aspx", "EditForm.aspx");
    window.location.replace(SecondURL);
}

Answer (score 0):

Try adding if statement to your code and put the logic to replace all instances of DispForm.aspx in the url. Something like this:

```
window.onload=function(){ 
        var ActualURL = window.location.href; 
        if (ActualURL.indexOf("DispForm.aspx") != -1)
        {           
            var SecondURL = ActualURL.replace(/DispForm.aspx/g , "EditForm.aspx");          
            window.location.replace(SecondURL);
        }       
    }
```

Comment: This still will not work from the link in the email. It's the Sharepoint generated email and it's just a flat email link with the ID at the end. Hitting the button again just refreshes the same page.

Answer (score 0):

I got this to work by creating a function and a button. I'm sure there is a more concise way to handle this but it worked.  Example:

**Function in Script Editor:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function myFunction(){
    var ActualURL = window.location.href;
    var SecondURL = ActualURL.replace("DispForm.aspx", "EditForm.aspx");
    window.location.replace(SecondURL);
}
</script>
```

**Function Called via Script Editor:**

```
<Input type="button" value ="CLICK me"onclick="myFunction()" />
```

Comment: This doesn't work when using the hyperlink from the system generated email.